# SQL query to delete rows of table in Server form another server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to write a query in Server1  to delete records from a table in server2.

I tried like this,

Sample Query

```
Declare  @EmployeeType nvarchar(50) = 'FACT'
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @ServerName nvarchar(max)='serverName';
DECLARE @DatabaseName nvarchar(max) = 'DBName';
DECLARE @UserID nvarchar(max) ='UserId';
DECLARE @DBPassword nvarchar(max) = 'Password';

    BEGIN
                SET @SQL = 'select * from Openrowset(
                            ''SQLNCLI'',
                            ''SERVER='+ @ServerName +';database='+ @DatabaseName +';UID='+ @UserID +';PWD='+ @DBPassword +''',
                            ''Delete from TimesheetToCPS where PAYGROUP =''' + @EmployeeType + ''' AND EMPLID IN (SELECT EmplId FROM #tmpEmplid ) AND DUR BETWEEN AND ''''' + CAST(@StartDate AS varchar(11))+ ''''' AND ''''' + CAST(@EndDate AS varchar(11))+ ''''')''
                                                            )'
            END  

        print @SQL
            EXEC(@SQL)
```

Passing all the parameter values. but not working Error -"Incorrect syntax near 'FACT'."
Anyone suggest me a alternative query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you mean by `not working` where you getting error ?

Comment: Can you not use a linked server? if you print instead of exec does it look right? try running that as a query? whats the error?

Comment: Error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Openrowset'. @dbajtr

Comment: the syntax is wrong for openrowset, should be select * from openrowset() look here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql

Comment: Tried select * from Openrowset() . My new query updated @dbajtr

Answer (score 0):

The error message provides the hint I believe. If you print the SQL you would get the query being passed as:

'Delete from TimesheetToCPS where PAYGROUP ='FACT' AND EMPLID IN (SELECT EmplId FROM #tmpEmplid ) AND DUR BETWEEN AND ''Apr  3 2018'' AND ''Apr  3 2018'')'

Here as you see you are having PAYGROUP ='FACT' and not PAYGROUP =''FACT''

Please try adding ''''' to this snippet and make it PAYGROUP =''''' + @EmployeeType + '''''